# How do I trace recursive function

Tags: c++

So in one of my class I am learning recursion and there is a question which I tried to trace through but couldn't get the right answer.

I keep geting 11 but the right answer is 6. Can someone help me get a better understanding and hopefully explain how you would trace through the code please. Thank you.

The way I tracing it right now:

```
int f(int x, int y) {
  if (x <= 0) {
     return y;
  }
  return f(x - 1, y + 1) - f(x / 2, y * 2);
}

What is f(4, -1)?
```

```
f(4,-1)
return   f(3,0) - f(2,-2)
return   f(2,1) - f(1,-4)
return   f(1,2) - f(0,-8)
return   f(0,3) - (-8)
return   3 + 8  = 11.
```

Comment: What do you mean by how do I trace the code.  You put it into a debugger and single-step through the code.  How are you doing it?

Comment: That's not how recursion works. The first recursive takes place, and only after it returns does the 2nd recursive call takes place. And when first recursive call takes place, guess what happens. `f()` is entered again, so there's going to be two more recursive calls, at least. And so on.

Comment: Ah, maybe this is your issue: typically debuggers step line by line, but with a line like "return f(x,y)" it runs the whole routine in one gulp.  The debuggers also typically have a "step into" button which takes you to the first line of the called code instead of running it in one gulp.

Comment: I have not yet learn about debuggers. I am just trying to wrap my head around the way the compiler is running. My teacher showed an example by writing each stack frames being created but when i try to do the same thing i just got lost.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/, the way you are calling it is wrong, you must calculate f(3,0) first before procede  to f(2,-2).
f(3,0) will get return f(2,1) -f(1,0) this too you must finish f(2,1) first before f(1,0
f(2,1) will get return f(1,2) - f(1, 2), finish f(1,2) first, and so on until it hit base case which is if(x<=0) return y, which will return the value to all its stack caller

Comment: I see so each time f() is called there are 2 new f(..) - f(..). Thank you so much

Comment: https://visualgo.net/en/recursion, here it has fibonacci example of recursive stack, try it maybe it helps too

Answer (score 4):

You are not taking into account that *most* of the calls to `f()` are then making **2** internal calls to `f()`.  So the real trace would break down more like the following.  The *real* answer is `2`, not `6` like your professor told you:

```
f(4,-1) = f(3,0) - f(2,-2)
    (
    f(3,0) = f(2,1) - f(1,0)
        (
        f(2,1) = f(1,2) - f(1,2)
            (
            f(1,2) = f(0,3) - f(0,4)
                (
                f(0,3) = 3
                )
                (
                f(0,4) = 4
                )
            = (3) - (4) = -1
            )
            (
            f(1,2) = f(0,3) - f(0,4)
                (
                f(0,3) = 3
                )
                (
                f(0,4) = 4
                )
            = (3) - (4) = -1
            )
        = (-1) - (-1) = 0
        )
        (
        f(1,0) = f(0,1) - f(0,0)
            (
            f(0,1) = 1
            )
            (
            f(0,0) = 0
            )
        = (1) - (0) = 1
        )
    = (0) - (1) = -1
    )
    (
    f(2,-2) = f(1,-1) - f(1,-4)
        (
        f(1,-1) = f(0,0) - f(0,-2)
            (
            f(0,0) = 0
            )
            (
            f(0,-2) = -2
            )
        = (0) - (-2) = 2
        )
        (
        f(1,-4) = f(0,-3) - f(0,-8)
            (
            f(0,-3) = -3
            )
            (
            f(0,-8) = -8
            )
        = (-3) - (-8) = 5
        )
    = (2) - (5) = -3
    )
= (-1) - (-3) = 2

final answer: 2
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/GOsrdE)

Comment: The answer 6 was given to me by my prof, this question was in one of my quiz. Thank you for putting in the effort explaining the whole process.

Comment: However, after looking through shouldn't it be - 2 instead of 2? Because you got that (-1) - in front. So after you should have  (-1) - ( f(0,0) - f(0,-2) ). leading to the final to be (-1) - 2 - 5 = -8?

Comment: @user12855799 Your prof gave you the wrong answer. I decoded the recursion by hand 3 times trying to get his answer (and got 3 different answers!), so I finally gave up and just [ran the code](https://ideone.com/Or2bRy), and then [wrote code to log what it actually does](https://ideone.com/GOsrdE). The correct answer is 2, not -2, as evident by actually running the code and having it spit out 2. And your math is wrong. I added some extra parenthesis to the logging so you can see what is actually being subtracted. Subtracting a negative number is the same as adding a non-negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Here is ASCII art with control flow for recursive call,

```
f(4,-1)-------->+
    .   //f(4 - 1, -1 + 1)
    .         f(3,0)------->+
    .           .           |
    .           .     //f(3-1,0+1)          
    .           .         f(2,1)----------->+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .      // f(2-1,1+1)    
    .           .           .           f(1,2)--------->+
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               .   //f(1-1,2+1)
    .           .           .               .       f(0,3)--------->+
    .           .           .               .           .       //as (x == 0) return 3
    .           .           .               .           .           |
    .           .           .               .           |<----(3)---+
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               .   //f(1/2,2*2)
    .           .           .               .       f(0,4)--------->+
    .           .           .               .           .       //as (x == 0) return 4
    .           .           .               .           .           |
    .           .           .               .           +<----(4)---+
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               .   //f(1-1,2+1) - f(1/2,2*2) = 3 - 4 = -1 
    .           .           .               +<---(-1)---+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .       // f(2/2,1*2)
    .           .           .           f(1,2)--------->+
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               .   //f(1-1,2+1)
    .           .           .               .       f(0,3)--------->+
    .           .           .               .           .    //as (x == 0) return 3
    .           .           .               .           .           |
    .           .           .               .           +<----(3)---+
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               .   //f(1/2,2*2)
    .           .           .               .       f(0,4)--------->+
    .           .           .               .           .   //as (x == 0) return 4
    .           .           .               .           .           |
    .           .           .               .           +<----(4)---+
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               .    //f(1-1,2+1) - f(1/2,2*2) = 3 - 4 = -1
    .           .           .               +<---(-1)---+
    .           .           +<----(0)-------+
    .           .           |
    .           .     //f(3/2,0*2)  
    .           .         f(1,0)----------->+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .       //f(1-1,0+1)
    .           .           .           f(0,1)--------->+
    .           .           .               .     //as (x == 0) return 1
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               +<----(1)---+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .       //f(1/2,0*2)
    .           .           .           f(0,0)--------->+
    .           .           .               .     //as (x == 0) return 0
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               +<----(0)---+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .       //f(0,1)-f(0,0) = 1- 0 = 0
    .           .           +<-----(1)------+
    .           .           |
    .           .   // f(3-1,0+1) - f(3/2,0*) = 0 - 1 = -1   
    .           +<----(-1)--+
    .           |
    .    //f(4/2,-1*2)
    .        f(2,-2)------->+
    .           .           |
    .           .       //f(2-1,-2+1)
    .           .         f(1,-1)---------->+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .       //f(2-1,-2+1)
    .           .           .           f(0,0)--------->+
    .           .           .               .   //as (x == 0) return 0
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               +<----(0)---+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .       //f(1/2,-1*2)
    .           .           .           f(0,-2)-------->+
    .           .           .               .   //as (x == 0) return -2
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               +<---(-2)---+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .       //f(0,0)-f(0,-2) = 0 - (-2) = 2
    .           .           +<----(2)-------+
    .           .           |
    .           .       //f(2/2,-2*2)
    .           .         f(1,-4)---------->+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .           f(0,-3)-------->+
    .           .           .               .   //as (x == 0) return -3
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               +<---(-3)---+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .           f(0,-8)-------->+
    .           .           .               .    //as (x == 0) return -8
    .           .           .               .           |
    .           .           .               +<---(-8)---+
    .           .           .               |
    .           .           .       //f(0,-3) -f(0,-8) = -3 -(-8) = 5
    .           .           +<-----(5)------+
    .           .           |
    .           .   //f(1,-1)-f(1,-4) = 2 - 5 = -3
    .           +<----(-3)--+
    .           |
    .   //f(4 - 1, -1 + 1) - f(4/2,-1*2) = -1 - (-3) = 2
    <----(2)----+
```

How to understand,

1. Each column represents a function call which makes 2 subsequent recursive calls.
2. `<--(x)---` represents return value `x`

When function f(x,y) is called, recursive call for f(x-1,y+1) is called until x is zero and then f(x/2,y*2) is called recursively.

Consider below case with f(1,2) call makes two subsequent recursive call to f(0,3) and f(0,4) and return value from both is computed back as return value of f(1,2)

```
f(1,2)--------->+
    .           |
    .   //f(1-1,2+1)
    .       f(0,3)--------->+
    .           .       //as (x == 0) return 3
    .           .           |
    .           |<----(3)---+
    .           |
    .   //f(1/2,2*2)
    .       f(0,4)--------->+
    .           .       //as (x == 0) return 3
    .           .           |
    .           +<----(4)---+
    .           |
    .   //f(1-1,2+1) - f(1/2,2*2) = 3 - 4 = -1 
    +<---(-1)---+
```

Let me try to put it in different way,
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't there a "(-1) -" in front of the 2 which changed positive 2 to negative?

Comment: Because f(3,0) after recursion will give you -1 and you will have [ -1 - ( f(0,0) - f(0,-2)) - ( f(0,-3) - f(0,-8) ) ] => -1 - 2 - 5 = -8? Or  since the recursion are separate that the negative sign from f(3,0) has no affect on changing the sign? I am so sorry this is confusing to understand...

Comment: @user12855799 : i have edited the answer. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can manually print out the traces. Probably not as good as a debugger in most cases, but it can occasionally come in handy. https://godbolt.org/z/WpSYNj

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int g_tabs = 0;
struct trace
{
  trace(int x, int y)
  { 
    for(int i = 0; i < g_tabs; ++i)
      std::cout << "  "; 
    std::cout << "f(" << x << ", " << y << ") {\n";
    ++g_tabs;
  }
  ~trace() 
  {
    --g_tabs;
    for(int i = 0; i < g_tabs; ++i)
      std::cout << "  "; 
    std::cout << "}\n";
  }
};
void print(int res)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < g_tabs; ++i)
      std::cout << "  "; 
    std::cout << "result[ " << res << " ]\n";
}
void print(int l, int r, int res)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < g_tabs; ++i)
      std::cout << "  "; 
    std::cout << "result[ " << res << " ] = " << l << " - " << r << '\n';
}

int f(int x, int y)
{
  trace t(x, y);
  if (x <= 0) {
     print(y);
     return y;
  }
  int left = f(x - 1, y + 1);
  int right = f(x / 2, y * 2);
  int result = left - right;
  print(left, right, result);
  return result;
}

int main()
{
    f(5, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is absolutely overkill. the poor guy is just trying to learn about recursion and you dump a struct constructor monstrosity on him? a simple print statement at the top of the f function - "f called with x= and y=" would be sufficient.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put in to help me understand and posted that but I have not yet at that level to understand such complexity. Thank you though